# Unity3D. How to move elements inside Vertical Layout Group?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to create chat window, and the messages must appears from side. So now I have the system with messages that placed inside of UI element with Vertical Layout Group, but I can't move the messages in horizontal axis, because position of messages is driven by Vertical Layout Group.
I had tried to do it by changing paddings but it works very ugly and I can't add messages into chat window and move them at the same time.
So is there a way to create custom appearance of messages in chat window that driven by Vertical Layout Group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting the labels directly into the VerticalLayoutGroup, put each of them into a seperate container, called ChatLine. ChatLine is just an empty GameObject with a RectTransform. Those ChatLines you put into the VerticalLayoutGroup.

```
VerticalLayoutGroup
  ChatLine
    Label
  ChatLine
    Label
```

VerticalLayoutGroup will arrange the ChatLine objects, putting one below the other. How you arrange the Labels contained in each of the ChatLines is up to you. You can move them horizontally as you please to create the effect your want.

Answer (score 0):

Vertical Layout Group has its limitations. You can look for more properties in VerticalLayoutGroup class via scripting but most likely you just have to create your own layout so you will have full control on position of every element.